# Javascript how to group logical or conditions with same prefix without repeating them?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, operators, repeat

I have seen things like:

```
if (a===1 ||a ===2 || a ===3 || a ===4) {...}
```

is it somehow possible to use brackets correctly to group the conditions, without repeating the prefix "a" all the time? e.g. like:

```
if ( a ===( 1 || 2 || 3 || 4)) {...}
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an exact match you can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to do this

```
if ([1,2,3,4].includes(a)) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with numbers, you could simple do:

```
if ([1,2,3,4].includes(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

another way its to find in array, like

```
[1,2,3,4].indexOf(a) !== -1
```

Comment: You can do the same thing like this `~[1,2,3,4].indexOf(a)`